# PCL feature matching failure

Tags: point-cloud-library

I am trying to match features between two point cloud I test by changing many parameters but it always produces wrong matches. I am calculating PFH feature descriptors of SIFT features.

Thank you for your suggestions.

**Below is the code I used**

```
// load the both point clouds
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("Tee.pcd", *cloud_1);
pcl::PLYReader Reader;
Reader.read("tee.ply", *cloud_2);
//pcl::io::loadPCDFile("Tee.pcd", *cloud_2);

    // Create the filtering object
pcl::PassThrough<pcl::PointXYZRGB> pass;
pass.setInputCloud(cloud_2);
pass.setFilterFieldName("z");
pass.setFilterLimits(0.0, 1.0);
//pass.setFilterLimitsNegative (true);
pass.filter(*cloud_2_filtered);


// Downsample the cloud
const float voxel_grid_leaf_size = 0.009f;
downsample(cloud_1, voxel_grid_leaf_size, downsampledCloud_1);
std::cout << "First cloud: downsampled " << std::endl;
const float voxel_grid_leaf_size2 = 0.003f;
downsample(cloud_2_filtered, voxel_grid_leaf_size2, downsampledCloud_2);
std::cout << "second cloud: downsampled " << std::endl;

// Compute surface normals
const float normal_radius = 0.03;
compute_surface_normals(downsampledCloud_1, normal_radius, normalsFromCloud_1);
compute_surface_normals(downsampledCloud_2, normal_radius, normalsFromCloud_2);
std::cout << "second cloud: normals computed " << std::endl;
// Compute keypoints
const float min_scale = 0.01;
const int nr_octaves = 3;
const int nr_octaves_per_scale = 6;
const float min_contrast = 1.0;
detect_keypoints(cloud_1, min_scale, nr_octaves, nr_octaves_per_scale, min_contrast, keypointsFromCloud_1);
std::cout << "first cloud: keypoints computed " << std::endl;
//const float min_scale1 = 0.1;
detect_keypoints(cloud_2_filtered, min_scale, nr_octaves, nr_octaves_per_scale, min_contrast, keypointsFromCloud_2);
std::cout << "second cloud: keypoints computed " << std::endl;
//visualize_keypoints(cloud_2, keypointsFromCloud_2);

// Compute PFH features
const float feature_radius = 0.08;
compute_PFH_features_at_keypoints(downsampledCloud_1, normalsFromCloud_1, keypointsFromCloud_1, feature_radius, descriptors1);
std::cout << "first cloud: descriptor computed " << std::endl;
compute_PFH_features_at_keypoints(downsampledCloud_2, normalsFromCloud_2, keypointsFromCloud_2, feature_radius, descriptors2);
std::cout << "second cloud: descriptor computed " << std::endl;

// Find feature correspondences
std::vector<int> correspondences;
std::vector<float> correspondence_scores;
find_feature_correspondences(descriptors1, descriptors2, correspondences, correspondence_scores);

// Print out ( number of keypoints / number of points )
std::cout << "First cloud: Found " << keypointsFromCloud_1->size() << " keypoints "
    << "out of " << downsampledCloud_1->size() << " total points." << std::endl;
std::cout << "Second cloud: Found " << keypointsFromCloud_2->size() << " keypoints "
    << "out of " << downsampledCloud_2->size() << " total points." << std::endl;

// Visualize the two point clouds and their feature correspondences
visualize_correspondences(cloud_1, keypointsFromCloud_1, cloud_2_filtered, keypointsFromCloud_2, correspondences, correspondence_scores);
```

**The resulting image is as shown:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data & Preprocessing

It seems like that you are trying to match a point cloud with only the object to a point cloud where the object is inside the scene.

In order to get consistent and robust results, extract all object from the scene beforehand and try to match the reference to all detected objects and select the best match.

### Descriptor

I experienced way better results using the **SHOT** descriptor rather than **PFH**.

**[Here](http://robotics.usc.edu/~potthast/06299166.pdf)** you can read more on **Object Recognition** from the authors of PCL where they describe and explain the whole pipeline for object recognition.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try the shot method. My aim is to estimate the 3D pose of the object, is there any better way to find it ?

Comment: Is it necessary to extact all objects from the scene beforehand ? If i use it for real time it might not be possible to extract the objects

Comment: From my experience, **SHOT** features were the most robust and consistent features for pose estimation.

Extracting all object from the scene beforehand is crucial to get good results. You can speed up the extraction by downsampling the input cloud first, and once you have the object instances, you can use the original resolution for the pose estimation.